# React - how to handle a cell click of a specific column of a datagrid table of material ui?

Tags: reactjs, click

I'm using a Material ui component called DataTable, and I don't know how to detect a click in any cell in a specific column

This is my table and I want to handle a click in any cell in the Action column:
[image]

below my component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

export default function DataTable({ rows, columns }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
}

DataTable.propTypes = {
  rows: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      conteudo: PropTypes.string,
      disciplina: PropTypes.string,
      curso: PropTypes.string,
      data: PropTypes.string,
    })
  ).isRequired,
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  columns: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can handle any click event on any column by passing [`onCellClick`](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/) prop to your `DataGrid` like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

export default function DataTable({ rows, columns }) {
  const [finalClickInfo, setFinalClickInfo] = useState(null);

  const handleOnCellClick = (params) => {
    setFinalClickInfo(params);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        onCellClick={handleOnCellClick}
      />
      {finalClickInfo &&
        `Final clicked id = ${finalClickInfo.id}, 
        Final clicked field = ${finalClickInfo.field}, 
        Final clicked value = ${finalClickInfo.value}`}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can access any property like `id`, `field`, `value` etc. from the value that is returned from `onCellClick` function. You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-datagrid-cell-click) for a live working example of this usage.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to modify onCellClick function handler to change the cell mode to 'edit'. For some reason the useDataApiRef hook does not work.

Comment: How do we listen to onclick only for a specific cell, for example 'age' in your example?

Comment: @mnagdev to listen for a specific cell just use an if inside `handleOnCellClick`. Something like: `if(params.field === '<FieldName>'){`